# Is that possible to do this = variable in Java?

Tags: java, variables, this, cluster-computing, minecraft

I am trying to make a clustered version of the official minecraft server. I decompiled it with MCP. Anything work... **But**, in some *void* the only thing which is affected is *this* , Which I send over the network and which is sent back to the normal class by the same way. The easiest way should be to simple write this `_this = receivedclass;_` . But it definitely does not work. Before changing anything to execute all change on the this class remotely, I want to be sure this is the only way to do this.

Comment: what is recieved class. Write simple two line method where you recieve input parameters and then compare.

Comment: No, it is not possible to assign anything to `this` in Java. You'll have to design your program in a different way.

Comment: @Jesper, thanks, I wanted to be sure before rewriting anything.

Comment: I have a feeling you're trying to do something *very naughty*, don't have a strong OOP background, and as a result have [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)ed yourself.

Comment: Even if you could assign to `this`, it would not make any changes to the object the method is called on, because Java is pass-by-value; you would just be making the local variable `this` point to a different object. In Objective-C before ARC, you could assign to `self` in any method, but again, doing so would not change the object the method was called on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to set `this`. You can however create a method which copies all values of the `receivedclass` object to `this` if the types are compatible. But i don't know if this is what you want.

Comment: The idea is to reduce latencies, I must test if that's a usable way for this.

Comment: There is no usual way to "set this" as it is not possible. copying all the values is the nearest you can get i think. Maybe that's not enough but then i can't help you. You should consider using an different approach for your project so you don't run into problems which are unsolvable in java.

Comment: This what I am doing, instead of modifying the class remotly I will do it in the normal way, and only the math part will be calculated on the node.